# Multiple Data Range in Pivot Table using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I tried looking around for a solution but couldn't find one. Appreciate all the help on this.

Can you please tell me if there is a way to have data from two different sheets as the data source in a pivot table using VBA?

**Example:** There is a default data in Sheet 1, the user then selects "Sheet 3" from a dropdown, therefore the vba should create a pivot table (or refresh the current pivot table) with the data source as a combination of Sheet 1 and Sheet 3. Similarly, if the user then selects Sheet 5, Pivot table should be combination of Sheet 1 + Sheet 5. Since I plan to keep adding data to the excel file, this would be very useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Everything you'd want to know about this: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html